# IntelliJ - SVN Checkout not clickable

Tags: svn, intellij-idea

Do you know why does my Checkout button is not clickable in IntelliJ ?

Browse SVN Repository -> right click -> (show window)

[image]

Answer (score 4):

In repository browser, the Checkout action is available for directories only. This is the same action as VCS - Checkout from Version control - Subversion, that is intended to checkout projects, not single files.

What is the use-case of checking out a single file? You could open it from the repository by using the Jump to source action if you need its content.
To get the different version of a file into existing project, use the Subversion - Update File... action from the file context menu in e.g. the Project tree.